# How to create a entity relation diagram (ERD)

Tags: r, graphviz, diagrammer

Does anyone know of a simple and easy method for creating entity relation diagrams (ERD) in R **besides graphviz and/or DiagrammeR**. I don't use graphviz much and often take more time than I'd like remembering it's syntax just to create a simple figure.

I'd like to create something similar to what Hadley Wickham has in his "[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html)" on the chapter about [Relational Data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html). The specific figure can be seen [here](https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/blob/master/diagrams/relational-nycflights.png).

Note: I don't know if this figure was actually done in R or not. I just like the layout and would like to be able to easily reproduce something like this in R.

Comment: [datamodelr](https://github.com/bergant/datamodelr) looks like it may do what you want.

Comment: The datamodelr package is now the [dm](https://cynkra.github.io/dm/) package. Note that its function for making ERD diagrams is built on DiagrammeR but the syntax is very simple (so if it's a syntax issue you have with DiagrammeR this should help, but if it's appearance/something else it might not).

Comment: Look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReDaMoR/vignettes/ReDaMoR.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **Jeffrey B. Arnold** has explained this in his book *R for Data Science: Exercise Solutions*. Please find the excerpt from exercise 13.3.3, chapter 13 below:

#### 1. OmniGraffle (default, what you see from the R4DS book)

R for Data Science uses database schema diagrams to illustrate relations between the tables. Most flowchart or diagramming software can be used used to create database schema diagrams, as well as some specialized database software. The diagrams in R for Data Science were created with [OmniGraffle](https://www.gliffy.com/), and their sources can be found in its [GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/tree/main/diagrams) repository.

#### 2. [datamodelr](https://github.com/bergant/datamodelr) package in R

Another option to draw database schema diagrams is the R package datamodelr, which can programmatically create database schema diagrams. The following code uses datamodelr to draw a diagram of the relations between the `Batting`, `Master`, and `Salaries` tables.

```
library(datamodelr)

dm1 <- dm_from_data_frames(list(
  Batting = Lahman::Batting,
  Master = Lahman::Master,
  Salaries = Lahman::Salaries
)) %>%
  dm_set_key("Batting", c("playerID", "yearID", "stint")) %>%
  dm_set_key("Master", "playerID") %>%
  dm_set_key("Salaries", c("yearID", "teamID", "playerID")) %>%
  dm_add_references(
    Batting$playerID == Master$playerID,
    Salaries$playerID == Master$playerID
  )

dm_create_graph(dm1, rankdir = "LR", columnArrows = TRUE) %>%
  dm_render_graph()
```

You will see:

[image]

Reference: https://jrnold.github.io/r4ds-exercise-solutions/relational-data.html#exercise-13.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who  would search for making entity relational diagram (e.g., for database models), as of now, the features of the datamodelr package are now included in the [dm](https://krlmlr.github.io/dm/) package.